# Can i edit an existing contact from ABaddressBook without ABPersonViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook, abpersonviewcontroller

I have created a custom address book that copy the native address book list with contacts. Now, in detail view controller I managed to ADD a new contact and REMOVE an existing contact from native address book. I want to edit an existing contact and save changes to native address book.

Answer (score 0):

The following example assumes that you have the ID of the record that you want to change in `recordID`,
and that you want to change its address to a new one stored in `addressDictionary`.

```
CFErrorRef error = nil;
const ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions (NULL, &error);
if (addressBookRef != nil) {
    ABRecordRef record = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBookRef, recordID);
    if (record != nil) {
        ABMultiValueRef addressesRef = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonAddressProperty);
        if (addressesRef != nil) {
            // Addresses found
            ABMutableMultiValueRef tmpAddressesRef = ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy(addressesRef);
            if (tmpAddressesRef != nil) {
                CFIndex addressIndex = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier (addressesRef,addressID);
                bool OK;
                OK = ABMultiValueReplaceValueAtIndex(tmpAddressesRef, (__bridge CFTypeRef)addressDictionary, addressIndex);
                if (OK) {
                    OK = ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonAddressProperty, tmpAddressesRef, &error);
                    if (OK) {
                        OK = ABAddressBookSave(addressBookRef, &error);
                        if (OK) {
                            // Do something
                        } else {
                            // Could not save address book
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Could not store modified address
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Could not replace address
                }
                CFRelease(tmpAddressesRef);
            } // Mutable copy of addresses could be created
            else {
                // Could not create mutable copy of addresses
            }
            CFRelease(addressesRef);
        } else {
            // Did not find addresses
        }
    } else {
        // Could not read record
    }
    CFRelease(addressBookRef);
}
else {
    // Could not open address book
}
```